# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SAT' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `ConsoleGames` wherein all columns are of type `varchar(50)`. When I try to create a new table `console_games` by amending existing datatypes by using the query:

```
CREATE TABLE console_games
(
    game_rank integer,
    game_name varchar(1200),
    platform_name varchar(1200),
    game_year integer,
    genre varchar(200),
    publisher varchar(1200),
    na_sales float,
    eu_sales float,
    jp_sales float,
    other_sales float
)

INSERT INTO console_games
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[RAWConsoleGames]
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SAT' to data type int.

When I look into the data in the table the value 'SAT' is in a column for which I am not changing the datatype. 'SAT' value exists in the `Platform` column which is of `varchar` type and I am not trying to change the type to int.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the schema of `RAWConsoleGames` as well!

Comment: Maybe the column order is different in both tables...

Comment: @mako exactly, but why should we try to guess?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis we can only wait for him...

Comment: Here is the schema for ConsoleGames (rank varchar(5000),
    name varchar(50),
    Platform varchar(50),
    year varchar(50),
    genre varchar(200),
    publisher varchar(1200),
    sales varchar(50),
    eu_sales varchar(50),
    jp_sales varchar(50),
    other_sales varchar(50)

Comment: So what would the following query output? `select count(*) from ConsoleGames where rank like '%SAT%'`

Comment: So, @JayEmm, any news at all?

Comment: There is no output on running the query. To add to earlier detail  - 'SAT' value exists in the Platform column of ConsoleGames table which is of varchar type and I am not trying to change the type to int.

Comment: Repeat for `game_year`... How do you **look** into the data?

Comment: Same result - there is no output

Comment: Are you running the `insert` query directly, or is it in a stored procedure (or from a client-side code)?

Comment: "No output" - you mean it returns 0, right?

Comment: I am running it directly

Comment: Yes - it returns zero

Comment: I am sorry I have no other ideas... Is there by any chance a computed column or a trigger or a constraint defined on the target table?

Comment: I think you should try to insert by explicitly define column name then you can understand the exact problem. Or if you are getting error in specific row the take value and individual and insert manually. if the problem solved then check the ASCII character of both values already inserted and new one.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly 'SAT' is not and will never convert to an INT.

Always best to specify the columns to insert ... things change

Now, if the source data is suspect, add a `try_convert()`.  If the conversion fails, a null value will be returned

I don't know the column names of your source, so I substituted SomeColN

```
INSERT INTO console_games
SELECT try_convert(integer      ,SomeCol1)
      ,try_convert(varchar(1200),SomeCol2)
      ,try_convert(varchar(1200),SomeCol3)
      ,try_convert(integer      ,SomeCol4)
      ,try_convert(varchar(200) ,SomeCol5)
      ,try_convert(varchar(1200),SomeCol6)
      ,try_convert(float        ,SomeCol7)
      ,try_convert(float        ,SomeCol8)
      ,try_convert(float        ,SomeCol9)
      ,try_convert(float        ,SomeCol10)
 FROM [dbo].[RAWConsoleGames]
```

**Just for fun, try:**

```
Select try_convert(int,'SAT')
Select try_convert(int,'25.25')
Select try_convert(int,'25')
```

Comment: Respectfully I disagree, `try_convert` would hide the problem, but not solve it (assuming that somehow false data have sneaked in the source table).

Comment: However, the advice "Always best to specify the columns to insert ... things change" is very important... I myself have been a victim of my own rush many times. [Still, this select * "technique" can reveal schema synchronisation problems, I guess there is no black/white here]

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis It is a choice.  One could let the entire job fail because of one bogus/unexpected value. Data-Hygiene is a constant battle.

Comment: It also depends on the stage of the work. Different needs exist in the early stage of ETL development and the production, day-to-day operation, where of course you probably don't want the job fail for one bogus value, but you certainly want this bogus value to be found and reported as well.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Personally, I load all data into a staging environment first.  This is where we run validation routines.  Depending on the issue we have Warning or Critical Failures.   One bogus Risk-Rating is only a warning, while double the data is a Critical Failure.   As you said, there is not black and white here  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** define the list of columns you're inserting into, and you should also always define the list of columns you're selecting from. Furthermore, I'd recommend to **explicitly** do any type conversions instead of leaving that up to SQL Server - if you do it yourself, you *know* when and what you're doing.

So I'd write that statement like this:

```
-- **DEFINE** the list of columns you're inserting into
INSERT INTO console_games (rank, name, Platform, year, genre, publisher, 
                           sales, eu_sales, jp_sales, other_sales) 
    -- **DEFINE** the list of columns you're selecting, and any conversions
    SELECT     
        game_rank, game_name, platform_name, 
        CAST(game_year AS VARCHAR(50)), genre,
        publisher, 
        CAST(na_sales AS VARCHAR(50)), 
        CAST(eu_sales AS VARCHAR(50)),
        CAST(jp_sales AS VARCHAR(50)),
        CAST(other_sales AS VARCHAR(50))
    FROM 
        [dbo].[RAWConsoleGames]
```